# Case.IsLocked Field in Salesforce

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-field, licenses

Can somebody please let me know , how can we enable the islocked field related to case object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This field is set to true only when your record is submitted for Approval.

But if you try to query in developer console. This field is not available.

In winter 16 release new feature is added for Lock/Unlock a record in Apex Code.

Lock records

```
Account[] accts = [SELECT Id from Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Acme%'];
// Lock the accounts
Approval.LockResult[] lrList = Approval.lock(accts, false);
```

Unlock records

```
Account[] accts = [SELECT Id from Account WHERE Name LIKE 'Acme%'];
// Unlock the accounts
Approval.UnlockResult[] lrList = Approval.Unlock(accts, false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the update but when I try to check in the workbench using select query it is giving us the data. In one of the sandbox but not in other.